# WatiN driving the IE "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" popup

Tags: watin

I'd like to extend my WatiN automated tests to drive a page that guards against the user accidentally leaving the page without saving changes.

The page uses the "beforeunload" technique to seek confirmation from the user:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (event) {
    if (confirmationRequired) {
        return "Sure??";
    }
});
```

My WatIn test is driving the page using IE.  I cannot find a way to get WatIn to attach to the popup dialog so I can control it from my test.

All the following have failed (where the hard-coded strings refer to strings that I can see on the popup):

```
Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Windows Internet Explorer");
browser.HtmlDialog(Find.FindByTitle("Windows Internet Explorer));
browser.HtmlDialog(Find.FindByTitle("Are you sure you want to leave this page?));
browser.HtmlDialog(Find.FindFirst());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to create and add the dialog handler.

**Example**  Go to example site, click link, click leave page on confirmation dialog:

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo("http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onbeforeunload.htm");

WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ReturnDialogHandlerIe9 myHandler = new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.ReturnDialogHandlerIe9();

browser.AddDialogHandler(myHandler);
browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("http://www.microsoft.com")).ClickNoWait();
myHandler.WaitUntilExists();

myHandler.OKButton.Click();
browser.RemoveDialogHandler(myHandler);
```

The above is working on WatiN2.1, IE9, Win7.  If using IE8 or before, you will likely need to use the `ReturnDialogHandler` object instead of the Ie9 specific handler

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm!  I'm curious about how I (or you!) could have known about the existence of the ReturnDialogHandlerIe9 class?  Is there some key documentation somewhere I'm not aware of?

Comment: I vaguely remembered there being a conversation with Jeroen on the mailing list when IE9 came out.  Between that memory and looking at the available Handlers via VisualStudio's IntelliSense I was able to connect the dots (with a bit of luck) and find the conversation on the mailing list archive and then put together the working example above.

Comment: Mailing list conversation:  http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTinLz35Gf1YxZRrdkNV621nV_sx%3DNw%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=watin-users

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to work with WatiN 2.1.0, IE9 (64bit), on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit). :-( I am diligently looking for another solution. I will update if I find one.

Comment: All my StyleIds appear to be what WatiN is looking for so your code should work. It also looks from reviewing commits that the ReturnDialogHandler should be smart enough to return the Ie9 version when the browser is Ie9.

Comment: After much trial and error I have discovered that if the IE Developer Tools window is showing when WatiN opens IE, then it cannot seem to handle the dialog. Ensuring that the window is not showing fixed my problem and your sample worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This works for my IE version 10.0.9200.16438 as well!

Comment: and IE 11 working, just make sure you use ReturnDialogHandlerIe9